# Where can I find a listing of all Emoji supported by OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, unicode, emoji

Are there any Cocoa APIs that I can call to get Emoji and their names? Is there a reference online with all the Emoji in their names in a plist? Are there any Cocoa libraries available for listing Emoji?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following project.

It has some classes where all emoji are classified by type.

Here is the URL:

https://github.com/limejelly/Emoji